# Get the delayed-load function binding correctly written into the image executable (dlltool)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, llvm, binutils, dlltool

I've been studying the delayed-load (delayimp) pipeline as a possible backend for the missing RPATH functionality on Windows, by the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int __declspec(dllimport) foo(int arg);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("foo() = %d\n", foo(foo(argc)));
    return 0;
}
```

Both GNU and LLVM implement delayed loading similarly with the "dlltool" (yet, LLVM's dlltool seems to have merged into "ld-link"). Essentially, the task performed in LLVM's `lld/COFF/DLL.cpp` or BinUtil's `dlltool.c` is two-fold:

1. Generate jump table stub for a delayed-load function (see example below)
2. Generate a trampoline that shall deploy the __delayLoadHelper2 code (see example below)

Upon the successful binding, the `__delayLoadHelper2` seems to write a resolved function address right into the executable code section:

```
extern "C"
FARPROC WINAPI
__delayLoadHelper2(
    PCImgDelayDescr     pidd,
    FARPROC *           ppfnIATEntry
    ) {
...
SetEntryHookBypass:
    *ppfnIATEntry = pfnRet; // access violation
...
}
```

In order for executable image modification, Microsoft has developed some fancy functions that temporarily add write permissions to the corresponding memory region.

**Now the question is:** the code to be modified is within the jump table stub that goes into ".idata" section, **and it fails to get write permissions**:

```
        if ((Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE) == 0) {

            //
            // This delay load helper module does not support merging the delay
            // load section to a read only section because memory management
            // would not guarantee that there is commit available - and thus a
            // low memory failure path where the delay load failure hook could
            // not be safely invoked (the delay load section would still be
            // read only) might be encountered.
            //
            // It is a build time configuration problem to produce such a
            // binary so abort here and now so that the problem can be
            // identified & fixed.
            //

/* Exception thrown at 0x000000013F3B3F3F in dlltool_test_executable.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading */
            __fastfail(FAST_FAIL_DLOAD_PROTECTION_FAILURE);
        }
```

So, currently the hard-binding does not work, and gives "write access violation". I'm wondering what kind of binary configuration am I missing here?

My test config: LLVM upstream from github, BinUtils upstream from git, MSVC2019, Windows 7.

```
$ cat trampoline.s
# Import trampoline
        .section        .text
        .global __tailMerge_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib
__tailMerge_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib:
        pushq %rcx
        pushq %rdx
        pushq %r8
        pushq %r9
        subq  $40, %rsp
        movq  %rax, %rdx
        leaq  __DELAY_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib(%rip), %rcx
        call __delayLoadHelper2
        addq  $40, %rsp
        popq %r9
        popq %r8
        popq %rdx
        popq %rcx
        jmp *%rax

# DELAY_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
.section        .text$2
.global __DELAY_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib
__DELAY_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib:
        .long 1 # grAttrs
        .rva    __C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib_iname        # rvaDLLName
        .rva    __DLL_HANDLE_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib   # rvaHmod
        .rva    __IAT_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib  # rvaIAT
        .rva    __INT_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib  # rvaINT
        .long   0       # rvaBoundIAT
        .long   0       # rvaUnloadIAT
        .long   0       # dwTimeStamp

.section .data
__DLL_HANDLE_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib:
        .long   0       # Handle
        .long   0

#Stuff for compatibility
        .section        .idata$5
        .long   0
        .long   0
__IAT_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib:
        .section        .idata$4
        .long   0
        .long   0
        .section        .idata$4
__INT_C__Users_marcusmae_dlltool_build_import_test_lib:
        .section        .idata$2
```

```
$ objdump -d dorks00000.o

dorks00000.o:     file format pe-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   ff 25 00 00 00 00       jmpq   *0x0(%rip)        # 6 <foo+0x6>
   6:   48 8d 05 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rax        # d <foo+0xd>
   d:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   12 <foo+0x12>
        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are generating the delay import structures using GNU dlltool, but linking against it with LLD or MS link.exe?

I think the difference here lies in the fact that GNU dlltool places the addresses that are updated at runtime within `.idata`, and GNU ld normally links `.idata` as writable, while LLD and MS link.exe normally has read-only `.idata` (and places the addresses that will be updated at runtime by the delay loading mechanism in `.data` instead).

LLD happens to have a bit of extra code to take read-write `.idata` sections from GNU import libraries and merge them into the rest of LLD's read-only `.idata` - which makes normal GNU import libraries work, but unfortunately breaks using it together with the GNU dlltool delayimport libraries.

So with LLD, just use LLD's built-in delay import mechanism, by passing e.g. `-delayload:user32.dll` when linking. This works when using MSVC style import libraries, but unfortunately not when using GNU style import libraries (import libraries generated by GNU dlltool or GNU ld).

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to combine MS link.exe with dlltool-generated import libraries, because I want to delay-load the libraries that were not initialially compiled for delay-load. That is, I need to provide new import libraries. I hope to get this done without touching the linker logic, as the import library is naturally a self-containing entity. Could you please kindly point me to where exactly the LLVM linker prepares ".idata" sections to be writable? GNU dlltool simply makes `INIT_SEC_DATA (IDATA5, ".idata$5", SEC_HAS_CONTENTS, 2)`, which does not make it writable.

Comment: LLD doesn't make the `.idata` sections writable, it places the corresponding data in `.data` instead. So for your case, you might want to change `.idata$5` into `.data$5`, and the same for `.idata$4` - that might work.

Comment: But for making MS link.exe delayload a library that is created using GNU ld, the easiest way might be to have GNU ld make a def file when linking (`-Wl,--output-def,mylib.def`), then create an import lib out of this using MS lib.exe (`lib.exe -machine:x64 -def:mylib.def -out:mylib.lib`), then link against this lib with MS link.exe, but passing the `-delayload` option, e.g. `link.exe [other options] mylib.lib -delayload:mylib.dll`. MS link.exe doesn't need a separate import library for delay import cases, as long as it's a MSVC style import library.

Comment: Chaning .idata$4 and .idata$5 into .data$4 and .data$5 resulted into a new access violation here: ```// Calculate the index for the IAT entry in the import address table
    // N.B. The INT entries are ordered the same as the IAT entries so
    // the calculation can be done on the IAT side.
    //
    const unsigned  iIAT = IndexFromPImgThunkData(PCImgThunkData(ppfnIATEntry), idd.pIAT);
    const unsigned  iINT = iIAT;

    PCImgThunkData  pitd = &(idd.pINT[iINT]);

    dli.dlp.fImportByName = !IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL(pitd->u1.Ordinal);```

Comment: Then try changing the other sections to .data as well; `.text$2` and `.idata$2` - all except for the first `.text` section that actually contains executable code.

Comment: Same error. After the either of two renamings, the value of `pidd->rvaIAT` changes to something not valid anymore (or unassigned)

Comment: Yeah, so I looked into the `objdump -h` of  the import library and the final executable. Turns out, the show stopper is the executable, where .idata comes `CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA`. While our import library has .idata with `CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA`. I guess the read-only attribute is added by the MSVC linker.

Comment: Solved by adding: `set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_test_executable PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/SECTION:.idata,RW")` Thanks, @mstorsjo !